# How to: inspect global variables in WordPress

Tags: globals

### People are often confused about how to get data from global objects/variables

**Question:** In which ways can you inspect global variables?

---

This Q was written because it's needed pretty often over here at WA. I just wanted to have it as a fav to link over here (people often don't take a look at github gist links).

*Feel free to modify the example if something is wrong or you think that the explanation is missing something. If you want to add other useful stuff, please add each as a single answer. Thank you.*

Comment: This should be a community wiki, or rephrased into a question.

Comment: @t31os Could you do this? I don't even know where i'd find a community wiki...

Comment: I think i could previously when in beta, not now though, the rep requirements are higher, might need to ask a higher rep user to mark the question as wiki, maybe @Rarst or @MikeSchinkel can..

Comment: @MikeSchinkel @Rarst @Jan Fabry - push

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How to inspect the data:

Use this to get an insight view of what you can use from the current request/wp_query.

```
function inspect_wp_query() 
{
  echo '<pre>';
    print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
  echo '</pre>';
}
// If you're looking at other variables you might need to use different hooks
// this can sometimes be a little tricky.
// Take a look at the Action Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
add_action('shutdown', 'inspect_wp_query', 999); // Query on public facing pages
add_action('admin_footer', 'inspect_wp_query', 999); // Query in admin UI
```

Btw:

```
    // this:
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query;
    // is the same as
    $wp_query;
    // and as this:
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'];

// You can do this with each other global var too, like $post, etc.
```

#### How to actually get the data:

```
// Example (not the best one)
(Object) WP_Query -> post (stdClass) -> postdata (Array)

// How to get the data:
// Save object into var
$my_data = new WP_Query; // on a new object
// or on the global available object from the current request
$my_data = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];

// get object/stdClass "post"
$my_post_data = $my_data->post;
// get Array
$my_post_data = $my_data['post'];
```

---

#### Examples

- [Generate a drop down/select object with all sidebars inside the `global $wp_registered_sidebars`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/list-all-sidebar-names/13453#13453)

Comment: Do you also have solution for successfully outputting `print_r($GLOBALS)` itself? Is that possible? I failed at it, meanwhile `var_dump($GLOBALS)` did it.

Comment: @ViktorBorítás I am not sure what you intend, but you can take a look at the _examples_  link. In any way, I'd recommend using XDebug and hook it up to your IDE (PhpStorm, Aptana, VS Code) to get proper debugging instead.

Comment: I was trying to print more readable list of all the globals (thus i thought `$GLOBALS` is an existing object that can be `print_r()`-ed as well, since `var_dump()` worked. Now, i'm just staying curious, why it didn't happen (at 'shutdown' hook). Tx for your suggestion about IDE integration tho, surely will go for it too.

Answer (score 12):

Or, if you're lazy, just install the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin.

It adds a button to the admin bar that, when clicked, reveals a panel with all kinds of useful information, including deprecation notices, WP_Query variables and an SQL query log.

Comment: Absolutely right. But it won't explain you how to access global variables/objects and how to get parts out of it.

Comment: Btw: Could you just add a short explanation on how this works? I guess it could/would really help extending this "how-to basics"-AQ.

Comment: @kaiser: Done .

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where in process of loading the scripts and rendering the final output, some of the above mentioned variables may not be present.  If you want a fairly inclusive view, perhaps a bit extreme, try:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

var_dump is also nice in that tell you the type and formats the data a bit.

Comment: hi, do you know the reason why `var_dump()` works in this case and `print_r()` doesn't? (throws 500 server error to me)