# List all sidebar names?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, sidebar, register-sidebar

I'm listing all sidebars like that:

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($wp_registered_sidebars); 
echo '</pre>'
```

So I'm getting something like:

```
Array
(
    [sidebar-1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sidebar #1
            [id] => sidebar-1
            [description] => Sidebar number 1
            [before_widget] => 
            [after_widget] => 
            [before_title] => 
            [after_title] =>
        )

 (...)

)
```

But I'd love to display them as a select list, like:

```
<select>
  <option value ="SIDEBAR-ID">SIDEBAR-NAME/option>
  <option value ="SIDEBAR-ID">SIDEBAR-NAME/option>
(...)
</select>
```

Wordpress Codex isn't helpful at all.

Thank you!

Comment: Where exactly are you listing the sidebars and what purpose does this serve?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Loop through the global:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['id'] ); ?>">
              <?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['name'] ); ?>
     </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Note: 
The `ucwords()` function is only there to display it exactly as you asked. Not sure if you really want that.

---

#### How to access global arrays & objects:

*Anyway:* Your Q mostly is about how to access arrays. I wrote a Q about that (for further explanation). [Please take a look over here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 6):

Write a function to create the list for you?

```
function sidebar_selectbox( $name = '', $current_value = false ) {
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    if ( empty( $wp_registered_sidebars ) )
        return;

    $name = empty( $name ) ? false : ' name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"';
    $current = $current_value ? esc_attr( $current_value ) : false;     
    $selected = '';
    ?>
    <select<?php echo $name; ?>>
    <?php foreach ( $wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar ) : ?>
        <?php 
        if ( $current ) 
            $selected = selected( $current === $sidebar['id'], true, false ); ?>    
        <option value="<?php echo $sidebar['id']; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $sidebar['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

Then just call it wherever you need to create a select list with the sidebars, optionally passing in a name, eg.

```
sidebar_selectbox();
```

or

```
sidebar_selectbox( 'theme_sidebars' );
```

Additionally and optionally, pass in a currently selected value...

```
sidebar_selectbox( 'theme_sidebars', $var_holding_current );
```

Hope that helps.