# List all sidebars in metabox

Tags: metabox, sidebar

I'm trying to add a metabox to select a sidebar per page. In order to create the metaboxes I use [this class](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html)

The construction is fairly easy:

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'sidebars_side',
    'title' => 'Page Sidebar',
    'pages' => array('page', 'post'),
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'low',

    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Sidebars',
            'id' => 'tst_sidebars',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(                      
                ARRAY OF SIDEBARS GOES HERE

            ),
            'multiple' => false,

        )
    )
);
```

But I can't for the love of God to construct the array properly. I checked [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/list-all-sidebar-names)

which is great, but I'm stuck somehow. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you are using accepts value => name pair in the select options array so

```
foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) { 
    $sidebar_options[$sidebar['id']] = $sidebar['name'];
}
```

and then you can use `$sidebar_options`.