# How to programmatically GET (to know) which Sidebar (or) which Menu is being used on Different Pages?

Tags: functions, widgets, sidebar

Lets say i want to detect such thing from the "functions.php" .. to know which `Sidebar` (or) which `Menu` is being loaded on current (whatever landed) page, how can i know?

Lets say i have a few pages, with:

- Page A (with Sidebar: "Today Weather" / Menu: "Apples")
- Page B (with Sidebar: "To-do List" / Menu: "Oranges")
- Page C (with Sidebar: "To-do List" / Menu: "Apples")
- Page D (with Sidebar: "Today Weather" / Menu: "Oranges")

From `functions.php`, if:

- there's the `Sidebar`: "To-do List" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition A";`.
- there's the `Sidebar`: "Today Weathers" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition B";`.
- there's the `Menu`: "Apples" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition C";`.
- there's the `Menu`: "Oranges" used, then i want to just `echo "Condition D";`.

So the thing here is:

- **How to KNOW the IDs of the things currently loaded.**

How to simply do it please.

Comment: Can I ask why you would need to know this, what are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: `Why`, is another story which i fairly suppose. There are a lot possibilities to do with, by knowing what are the things being rendered on a page. Here something like, i have to apply different styles (and DOM structure modifications also) differently on different sidebars (and items inside). I would really appreciate for any help on `How`. :)

Comment: are you looking to register a new sidebar so you can use more widgetized areas in your theme? or are you looking to have different widgets on different pages? Or are you just trying to echo something on the page to tell you what its using?

Comment: If you need completely different dom structures this implies you are using inflexible JS. CSS isn't an issue if you're using the `body_class` function to set body tag css classes, as you'd be able to match on the theme/page template in the body tag to apply different CSS on different types of pages

Comment: I understand what it implies to. But please can i just know how to get the ID of current sidebar? Please :S

Comment: Have you tried `get_option('sidebars_widgets')` on the page you want to find out the sidebar on

Comment: Is **[this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13453/385)** what you are searching for? Please ping me here in the comments using `@kaiser` if so. Thanks.

Comment: giollianosulit / kaiser, No. Both can not determine whether a sidebar is SPECIFICALLY loaded on the CURRENT page or not. It can just list down the registered sidebars in the system. Can not say which one is loaded NOW.

Comment: I have edited the whole question. Please kindly check again :)

Comment: Typically the opposite is done: you know where you are (page, post, archive, taxonomy, etc) and load the sidebar and menus you want with the styles and DOM structure you want. Manipulate them in front end, if needed, is quite easy because the widget and menus already have assigned specific IDs and classes. I don't get the point of getting that information information on functions.php and I think there is no way beacuse the sidebars are loaded in the template files; there no assigned sidebars to specific template file, you choose them in the template file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar generator plugin is best solution for your logic?

If you would like to add sidebar even in taxonomy or tag, you would need to create meta field or option field for that.

Below example codes is good for static sidebar!

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'left' ); ?>
<?php get_sidebar( 'right' ); ?>
```