# How-to inspect filter-able $vars?

Tags: customization, filters

*Note: This is more of a tutorial/wiki than a real question and should be a reference for later Questions. If you got something to add, please feel free to add an answer. Working answers get upvoted. :)*

---

#### Scenario

You want to modify the output of some wp core function and instead of modifying the core directly (which is always bad), you have found a call like this:

`$filterable_var = apply_filters( 'name_of_filter', $filterable_var );`

The filter function allows you to modify eg. `$filterable_var` and therefore the output of the wp function.

#### The Problem

You don't know what exactly the function wants as input.

#### The Tags

Check what you can modify.

---

Possibly Related Q:
*[Fell free to add your own Questions here.]*

- [How-to inspect global variables?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel @Rarst I think this should be a community wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example

Nav menu walker - allows adding eg. css classes to (all) menu items.

```
// copyied from /wp-core/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php > line 76 (wp 3.1.1) - start_el() function
$class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
```

Now let's check the $var:

```
function wpse15319_check_nav_menu_classes( $classes ) 
{
    // You can take any of the $vars from the core function above: $classes, $item, $args
    echo '<pre>';
        // nice list:
        print_r( $classes ); 
        // or check of what type the $var is
        var_dump( $classes );
    echo '</pre>';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse15319_check_nav_menu_classes', 10 );
```

#### Modify - Applied example

```
function wpse15319_add_nav_menu_classes( $classes ) 
{
    $classes[] = '';
    $classes[] .= 'my added css classes'; 

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse15319_add_nav_menu_classes', 10 );
```

Comment: nice but what do you do when you don't have apply_filters hooks and don't want to modify the core files???

Comment: @Bainternet - open a new Q here on WA and give an answer to that ,) - (and link to that at the bottom of the Q)

Comment: if only i knew the answer... :)

Comment: @Bainternet: easy ... fork, mod & redistribute wp ,)