# show term description instead of list terms of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, description

For a custom post type (review) I have enabled a few custom taxonomies. One of them is author rating and for that I have added images to the description field of the terms in the taxonomy (1 star to 5 stars).

Now I am wondering how to show that description instead of the term itself on the `single-review.php`?

I am already using the function to allow XHTML in category descriptions as per Justin Tadlock's function described on [his website](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/06/04/using-custom-taxonomies-to-create-a-movie-database)

Comment: Could you please show the code from `single-review.php`?

Comment: sure, you can find it on: http://pastebin.com/K12Npptz I wrote in Capitals where I would like to show the description of the term instead of the term itself

Comment: Take a look at `/wp-includes/category-template.php` on line 1113 and the filter `"term_links-$taxonomy"`.

Comment: @kaiser, I am not sure I follow you. The filter says `$term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $term_links );`
I have to wiggle description somewhere in there?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15319/how-to-inspect-filter-able-vars)

Comment: @kaiser although I appreciate that you don't want to chew it out for me, so all I need to do is copy and paste (and hopefully learn sth new in the process), this is way over my head at the moment, I don't even have a clue where to look.
So, I will sleep a night on it and then ask my question again in a different way. Thanks anyways for your efforts.

Comment: @kaiser btw re the `category-template.php` you referred to earlier didn't you mean line 1054: `function term_description( $term = 0, $taxonomy = 'post_tag' ) {` instead of line 1113?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you are trying to achieve then you can use `get_the_terms` function to get the rating terms object and from that echo out the description.

replace:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'rating', __('Author Rating: ', 'appz'), ', ', '' ); // HERE I WANT THE DESCRIPTION (I.E. THE IMAGE THAT I USED AS THE DESCRIPTION INSTEAD OF THE TERM) ?>
```

with:

```
<?php 
    echo '<span class="rating-author">'.__('Author Rating: ', 'appz').'</span>';

    $reating_terms = get_the_terms ($post->id, 'rating');
    foreach ($reating_terms as $term){
        echo $term->description;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bainternet, that is exactly what I wanted to accomplish!
To let me understand what you did to accomplish this result, you basically created a new filter, correct? I still have to learn that you can basically create any type of filter this way... What I don't understand though is why there is no need to end the `foreach`...

Comment: no filter here , just queried the terms of the taxonomy 'rating' that this post have. as for the foreach, you can end it with `foreach($bs as $b) : //doo stuf end foreach` or use brackets `foreach($bs as $b) { //doo stuf }`