# Wordpress 3.1.2 Bug: add_theme_support() and video post format registering twice

Tags: customization, metabox, post-formats

Ive been experiencing a problem with the new WordPress 3.1.2 update. When i use `add_theme_support();` and register an array of post formats, it registers all of them fine, but when it comes to the video post format, it registers it twice, and gets called **post-format-video-2**.

This is the way im writing out the code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'video' ));
```

Ive tested this out both on my theme, and the twentyten theme. The problem is exclusive to the video post-format. Its really strange. Additionally when you declare a "posts" format as "video" upon publishing or updating, the post-format meta box adds a new radio button with a new post format without a slug/name.

Illustration (where numbers are the radio buttons):

1. Aside
2. Gallery
3. Image
4. Link
5. Video
6. 

Despite only showing 5 radio buttons, upon updating/publishing, a new radio button appears, and it gets selected (radio button 6) rather than the one I chose (radio button 5).

Ive used the `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'foobar' );` on my theme with no luck. Of-course this comes standard with twentyten.

Any ideas?

Comment: First guess - do you have a term already registered called "post-format-video"? It sounds like a term with that slug must already be in your wp_terms table (maybe attached to a different taxonomy, though I can't imagine why that would be)...

Comment: You should report this to the wp-hackers list and ask if you should put it on wp-trac.

Comment: @goldenapples: Yea it does exist, which is why i find it odd. There are two slugs post-format-video and post-format-video-2, with the names Video, and post-format-video respectively.

Comment: @kaiser: will do. Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe one of you guys can try to recreate it in a local environment before i create a ticket?

Comment: maybe it has to do with that the proper way to add the Post Formats to a Child Theme of Twenty Ten is to include (and bump up) the priority? More info on this via http://wpti.ps/?p=95 (see update) or http://senl.in/m7RjER

Comment: @piet My theme is independent of twentyten tho. I sent an email to the wp hackers list, informing them of the problem.

Comment: @VicePrez - i guess you updated from an older version? The point is that 'post_formats' is just a built in taxonomy. So i guess you made some update where it went wrong. You should anyway inspect the global `$wp_taxonomies` first (this will help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress) - I guess it contains it two times: post-format-video & post-format-video-2 and something went wrong with the first one, so a second one got registered, but has the wrong index/key for some function...

Comment: @kaiser: i opened up MySQLWorkbench and deleted both rows. I then reloaded the local site, created a new post under the video post format and the problem got resolved. Now it only registers one video post format in the meta box (and wp_terms table). I'm not sure if this is considered a qualitative solution.

Comment: I still wonder what exactly caused the miss interpretation wp made and therefore created the video format again. Guess this will stay in dark :)

Comment: @piet - the `after_setup_theme` hook loads exactly after the child themes functions.php and then the parent themes functions.php was loaded. So you have to hook all setup stuff in there in a child themes functions.php to not miss anything that get's loaded by the parent.

Comment: @kaiser, you mean that the bumping of the priority is not necessary? If that is the case (and I'm going a bit off-original-topic now), what would then be the proper way of doing that? As you can see from the post I referred too, there are more people with this problem and it is not really very well documented...

Comment: @piet: Bumping the priority is still needed I think. The child `functions.php` will load first, then the parent `functions.php` (so you can define functions first your child theme). If you hook into `after_setup_theme` in both files, the child's will be executed first, which is not what you want. So you must increase the priority to have it execute after the parent.

Comment: @piet - reading my comment now: it's not really english. @Jan Fabry wrote exactly the same in some understandable well written sentences. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @goldenapples and @kaiser for their guidance. Apparently (for some odd reason) i had two terms registered with post-format-video. Im not sure if the following can be a viable solution to the problem, but i fired up Workbench and deleted both rows in the wp_terms table. I then reloaded the local site, created a post under the video post-format, and finally.. its resolved. One "video" post-format was registered both in the post-format meta box and the wp_terms table.

I'll leave the intricacies of why this happened and how this worked to the wise.

Either way. I reported this problem to the wp hackers list.

Thanks guys.