# Different Menus based on Category Page

Tags: menus

I was trying to set up different menus based on what category "page" you were on using the built in Wordpress menu editor.

In my header file I set up:

```
<?php
    if (is_home()) {
    $menu = 'home';}

    elseif($post->post_name='category-aviation'){
    $menu = 'aviation';}



    elseif($post->post_name='category-anti-terrorism'){
    $menu = 'anti-terrorism';}
        elseif($post->post_name='asbestos'){
    $menu = 'asbestos';}
        elseif($post->post_name='burn-pits'){
    $menu = 'burn-pits';}
        elseif($post->post_name='catastropic-injury'){
    $menu = 'catastrophic-injury';}
        elseif($post->post_name='medical'){
    $menu = 'medical';}

        elseif($post->post_name='securities'){
    $menu = 'securities';}

    //get_category_by_slug('aviation')
    ?>
```

And I was calling the menu like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(  'theme_location'  => "$menu" , 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
```

I set up the functions.php file with:

```
function show_posts_nav() {
    global $wp_query;
    return ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1);
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

}

if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
          'home' => 'The Home Menu',
          'aviation' => 'Aviation',
          'anti-terrorism' => 'Anti-Terrorism',
          'asbestos' => 'Asbestos',
          'burn-pits' => 'Burn Pits',
          'catastrophic-injury' => 'Catastrophic .Injury',
          'medical' => 'Medical',
          'securities' => 'Securities'




        )
    );
}
```

None of the menus are showing up however. Am I doing something wrong here? I know the body class is set to "class="archive category category-aviation category-5 logged-in admin-bar" when I am on the aviation page.

Comment: have you tried to use the conditional tag `is_category()` ? example: `elseif( is_category('aviation') ){     $menu = 'aviation';}`

Comment: Thanks @michael. That worked like a charm. I appreciate the help!

Comment: can you post what the final code looked like as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

### Outlining your concept

As far as i can see, you want to do the following:

1. Check if there is more than one page (`$GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages > 1`)
2. If `TRUE`, add your nav menus

The concept fails in some points (more explanation at the end of the answer):

1. You're questioning too early if there's more than one page. (Your idea really is to only show these menus if you're on page 2 of a paginated archive?)
2. You're looking into `$post->post_name` without a) having the data available from the global b) outside the loop and c) from the wrong global

#### Make your life easier

In your `functions.php` file you can add the menu like this:

```
function wpse19269_add_nav_menus()
{
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );

    $nav_menus = array(
         'home'          => 'The Home Menu',
         'aviation'      => 'Aviation',
         'anti-terrorism'    => 'Anti-Terrorism',
         'asbestos'      => 'Asbestos',
         'burn-pits'         => 'Burn Pits',
         'catastrophic-injury'   => 'Catastrophic Injury',
         'medical'       => 'Medical',
         'securities'        => 'Securities'
    );
    register_nav_menus( $nav_menus );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse19269_add_nav_menus', 20 );
```

If you're using the `functions.php` file, you can write your own custom functions and avoid cluttering your thems files:

```
function wpse19269_show_nav_menus()
{
    $menu = ''; // Set a value to avoid errors if no condition is met
    if ( is_home() )
    {
        $menu = 'home';
    }
    elseif( is_category('some_category') )
    {
        $menu = 'whatever';
    }
    elseif
    {
        // and so on...
    }

    // Nav Menu
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
         'theme-location'   => $location
        ,'menu'         => 'top-nav'
        ,'menu_id'      => 'top-nav'
        ,'container'        =>  false
        ,'container_class'  => 'menu-header' 
    ) );
}
// Use it in your theme like this:
// wpse19269_show_nav_menus();
```

---

*After reading through your snippets, I think it's best to explain some basic things:*

#### Global Variables

If you want to access `global` available `$variables`, you'll have to first call them as `global $whatever` before you use it inside your function.

**Example:**

```
function the_example()
{
    global $post; // Now we have the global data available in the function
    echo $post->post_title; // This is the post title - must be used inside the loop
}
```

You can read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress) more about it.

#### Interacting with data in hooks

Please take a look at the [Plugin API/Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see when `$wp_query` is ready and available. You call on the `init` hook is too early.

#### Conditional Tags

Use other [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), like [`is_category('see codex link for more information');`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category).

Some other notes regarding your code:

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'  => "$menu" ...` should be written without the `"`.

#### WordPress functions

You don't have to question `if ( function_exists('some_native_wp_fn') ) {`, because it will exist. If doesn't exist anymore, you'll get a `depracated` notice that tells you about it. If you question the existance you suppress the notice and won't be able to fix it (or have a hard time finding it).