# Pagination that includes "view all on one page"

Tags: pagination

I'm using the code below to create pagination for my post results, it works fine but is it possible to add a "view all posts on one page" button to the pagination?

This would presumably override the pagination code and just display everything all posts on one page.

```
function numeric_pagination ($pageCount = 9, $query = null) {

if ($query == null) {
    global $wp_query;
    $query = $wp_query;
}

if ($query->max_num_pages <= 1) {
    return;
}

$pageStart = 1;
$paged = $query->query_vars['paged'];

// set current page if on the first page
if ($paged == null) {
    $paged = 1;
}

// work out if page start is halfway through the current visible pages and if so     move it accordingly
if ($paged > floor($pageCount / 2)) {
    $pageStart = $paged - floor($pageCount / 2);
}

if ($pageStart < 1) {
    $pageStart = 1;
}

// make sure page start is 
if ($pageStart + $pageCount > $query->max_num_pages) {
    $pageCount = $query->max_num_pages - $pageStart;
}

?>
<div id="pagination">
<?php
if ($paged != 1) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link(1); ?>" class="numbered page-number-first">  <span>&lsaquo; <?php _e('Newest', 'rhinoplasty'); ?></span></a>
<?php
}
// first page is not visible...
if ($pageStart > 1) {
    //echo 'previous';
}
for ($p = $pageStart; $p <= $pageStart + $pageCount; $p ++) {
    if ($p == $paged) {
?>
    <span class="numbered page-number-<?php echo $p; ?> current-numeric-page"><?    php echo $p; ?></span>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link($p); ?>" class="numbered page-number-<?    php echo $p; ?>"><span><?php echo $p; ?></span></a>

<?php
    }
}
// last page is not visible
if ($pageStart + $pageCount < $query->max_num_pages) {
    //echo "last";
}
if ($paged != $query->max_num_pages) {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link($query->max_num_pages); ?>" class="numbered page-number-last"><span><?php _e('Oldest', 'rhinoplasty'); ?> &rsaquo;</span></a>
<?php } ?>

</div>

<?php }
```

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Changing to different pagination code is also fine if that will work better.

Just to clarify my question, I want to add a 'view all posts on one page' functionality, basically over-riding the pagination code - this would be done by clicking a "view all" link to the right of the pagination menu ( 4  5  ... last  Next >> View All> ).

Update - almost there I think:

I've added this:

```
<?php 
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI='http://sitename.com'.$Path;
$nopage = add_query_arg( 'paged', 'no', $Path );
?>

<a href="<?php echo $nopage; ?>">View All</a>
```

Which reloads my page with sitename.com?paged=no, but it still shows pagination - I'm not sure how to override the pagination.

UPDATE:

Here is how I ended up solving it in case this helps anyone else.

After the above code and before the final  I added:

```
if (isset($_GET['viewall']))

{

function view_allposts( $query ) {

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'view_allposts' );

}


if(!$_GET['viewall']){ ?>

<a class="numbered" href="<?php  echo add_query_arg( array( 'viewall' => "true" ), get_pagenum_link(1) ); ?>">Show All >></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Works perfectly!  Thanks for your help on this Kaiser, although I used a different solution I learned a lot from the links you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) and change `$paged` for the old query.

**EDIT:**

```
//  This should output 'http://example.com/?paged=no'
add_query_arg( 'paged', 'no', bloginfo('url') );
```

Then use [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to modify the output.

Comment: Thanks kaiser, how would I implement that?

Comment: See edited A...

Comment: I've been trying to work this out but my knowledge is pretty limited, do you think you could give me a bit more detail on how to make this work?

Comment: Sure. Just post what you already tried, then I'll help you with the next step.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, couldn't get to my work computer this weekend!  I've edited the above to show what I've come up with (not much unfortunately)

Comment: See above, I've added my code that is almost working, pagination still remains though.

Comment: Just inspect the query and use an if/else statement to return instead of showing the query.

Comment: Btw: If you want to learn more about pagination, take a look at my pagination plugin [at github](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon).

Comment: Do I add the if/else statement on the functions.php file (where the pagination code resides) or on the page where I'm calling     <?php numeric_pagination(); ?> ?  Thanks, I can see what you're saying way up above my head there but I'm not taking it all in.

Comment: Imo best place would be inside the pagination function to not clutter all templates with repetitive code lines. This let the function then die/return/abort silently when not used. So something like `if ( ! $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars->whatever_the_code_is ) return;`. Btw: You could take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21086/wordpress-include-templatepath-or/21093#21093) answer for a more insight view about pathes and urls.

Comment: I appreciate your help but you're assuming too much knowledge on my part I think, how exactly would I fit this into the above pagination function?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress) I wrote to help understanding a simple debug process/approach. This will help you understanding `$wp_query` and arguments like `$paged` better. Code always runs line after line. So start dumping at the top of your function and then go down until you reach a point where you can edit the `$paged` var with the `if/else` statement. If you edit your code, please update the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Filter `'pre_get_posts'` and set the `nopaging` parameter to true.

I have written a small tutorial about this: [How To List All Posts Of An Archive, A Category Or A Search Result](http://wpengineer.com/2031/how-to-list-all-posts-of-an-archive-a-category-or-a-search-result/).

Comment: That is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

My company just released a plugin that offers publishers the option of including a "single page" link in their pagination strings: [Page-Links Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-single-page-option/).