# WordPress "include TEMPLATEPATH" or?

Tags: widgets, include

I built something like this:

**Index Container Widgets Area**

and I created a widget for that -

**Categories Widget - Index Container .php**

with this in:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/containers/container-grid-categories.php'); ?>
<?php ///include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/containers/container-list-categories.php'); ?>
```

and for example in the 
/includes/containers/**container-grid-categories.php**

is this:

```
<?php   //include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/containers/container-grid-categories/grid-thumbs.php'); ?>
<?php  include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/containers/container-grid-categories/grid-tumbs-details.php'); ?>
```

So, my questions, with this everything is working fine, the question is this a good way to make what I did (include TEMPLATEPATH)? Or use another way, and if that what way?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Long answer short: the absolute-best answer, for template-part files in a subdirectory, is to use `locate_template()`**

I would recommend referencing the *stylesheet* path for *template file* includes, so that those template part files can be easily over-ridden by Child Themes. So, ideally, you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Some differences/explanation of all the functions listed by @kaiser:

- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`/`get_template_directory_uri()` return a *URL*
- `get_stylesheet_directory()`/`get_template_directory()` return a *file path*
- All four of the `*get_*_directory_*()` functions perform *SSL checking*
- `TEMPLATEPATH`/`STYLESHEETHATH` are simple constants, return a *file path*, and do *not* perform SSL checking

So, the four `get_*_directory_*()` functions are preferred to using `TEMPLATEPATH`/`STYLESHEET`; however, they aren't really intended for locating template part files in subdirectories. In such a case, the best option is to use `locate_template()` directly. ([See here for a great writeup and comparison of all of the above options.](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes))

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to acchieve this:

```
    TEMPLATEPATH // Path to your (parent) themes root dir
    STYLESHEETPATH // Path to your parent/child - if present - dir
    get_template_directory_uri();
    get_template_directory();
    get_stylesheet_directory();
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

    // to load a file: path_and_file_name.php which searches in child dir first, then parent themes dir
    get_template_part( 'path_and_file_name' ); // appends .php automagically
    get_template_part( 'path_and_file_name', 'suffix' ); // loads: path_and_file_name-suffix.php

/**
 * Directoy structure
 * @return (array) $dir_struct | directory structure
 */
function wpse21093_get_dir_struct()
{
    $dir_base  = get_template_directory().'/includes/';
    $dirs[] = 'containers';
    // add more folders
    // $dirs[] = 'widgets';
    foreach ( $dirs as $dir )
    {
        $dir_struct[ $dir ] = trailingslashit( $dir_base.$dir );
    }
    return $dir_struct;
}

/**
 * Loading files for larger structures the *smart* way ...
 * Searches in all folders supported by the theme, defined by the user
 * Allows a {$suffix} to be appended to mimic the get_template_part(); behavior
 */
function wpse21093_load_file( $file_name, $suffix = '' )
{
    $dirs = wpse21093_get_dir_struct();
    foreach ( $dirs as $supported => $dir )
    {
        if ( empty ( $suffix ) )
        {
            if ( file_exists( $dir.$file_name.'.php' ) )
               require_if_theme_supports( $supported, $dir.$file_name.'.php' );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( file_exists( $dir.$file_name.'-'.$suffix.'.php' ) )
               require_if_theme_supports( $supported, $dir.$file_name.'-'.$suffix.'.php' );
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Then call it like this:
add_theme_support( 'containers' ); // add support for folder
wpse21093_load_file( 'container-grid-categories' );
```