# Custom URl parameter

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

i have Wp blog that need to receive a custom paramter on category page for filter the posts like my rule.

For example:

> http://mysite.com/category/teste?myvar=ABC

How can I get the myvar from URL? I tried a lot of examples on the web, but no one works for the category page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this code.

```
add_filter( 'category_link','append_parameter', 10, 2 );

function append_parameter( $link, $my_parameter ) {
$my_parameter = $_GET['sort']; //get sort value       
if ( isset($my_parameter) ) { 
    $link = add_query_arg( 'sort', $my_parameter, $link );
}
    return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
<?php
$myvar = $_GET['myvar'];
?>
```

and to make sure, u could also put this code in any page to test it:

```
<?php
echo $myvar;
?>
```

This is simply the $GET[] function in PHP.

I hope it helps, and for more info visit this [website](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php).

Comment: Thanks Khalid, but when I use this code, the Wordpress just redirect for the same page without this parameter, I think that it does not accept.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at this Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress) and how to inspect the global `$wp_query;`. Then just get the relevant part (everything explained in my A).

Comment: Thanks Kaiser but does not solve this problem. I already can't get a custom parameter on URL.

Comment: @Marcomar When you retrieve `$wp_query`, then you already got every available parameter. As far as I understand your needs, your problem is that you want to **add** a custom parameter(/query_var) and **not** retrieve it. Else you're absolutely fine with playing with `$wp_query` - the only problem then is that you don't know how to handle php and query stuff (in this case, provide a code sample).