# No Error Log File, no debug info

Tags: plugin-development, errors, customization

My error when writing a plugin for uploads

and yes, I can debug. But it just jumps directly from this line to `destruct`

[image]

the end of my `wp-config.php` **EDIT:**

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

(yes i did restart)

My webcontent folder

[image]

So now what?

How do I find out what is the problem?

**EDIT** it's not file permission as I can do
`error_log("errrorrrr ", 3 , "..../debug.log")`

In my plugin I wrote the line

`throw new \Exception("foo");`

I want to get to see the error in my debug.log file

Comment: You have to create the debug.log file in wp-content/ for debug logging to work.

Comment: @mike23 no didn't help, I  used as well ```error_log("errrorrrr ");```

Comment: Side note. Have you checked permissions. Permission to write to debug.log.

Comment: hehe I hate to admit it, but this is windows.
I am able to write there with ```error_log("errrorrrr ", 3 , "..../debug.log")```

Comment: You said "the end of my `wp-config.php`"... Is it literally the end? Constants definition goes before the line `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` or it does nothing...

Comment: Make sure you disk-space is not full

Comment: @gmazzap alright it was at the end of the config. I now changed it (see edited post), but debug log still is empty. Am I right to assume that, say,  a ```throw new \Exception("foo");``` in a plugin that gets called, should generate an entry in `debug.log`? The disk is not full, it's my windows machine.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions on the folders? If it can't upload AND it can't log... does it have permission? I have had to use 777 sometimes for localhost.

Comment: What is error_reporting set to in your php.ini file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Insert this into your wp-config.php

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Before

`/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`

Comment: the `@ini_set('display_errors',0);` isn't necessary. `define('WP_DEBUG', true);
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` are essential. Also, be sure about `chmod` ing the folders correctly, e.g. wordpress needs to be able to have write access to that folder (for ubuntu `chmod ug+rw -R /folder/to/wordpressinstall` )

Comment: A bunch of errors in the control panel wouldn't look good, that is why I added `@ini_set('display_errors',0);`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when the permissions on the upload dir were not allowing the upload, try that first. Take a look at the codex [Changing_File_Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) for more info.

Alternatively, check that the uploads dir is owned by the same user (on the server) as Wordpress, it's also mentioned in the above link.

For how to... please find someone with more experience ;)

Comment: i can write to the debug.log file using a special command, see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Toskan,

It seems like your wordpress file is not uploaded, so there may be a possibility for one or more issue, Please read out following and apply these solution one by one:

> > Large images require more memory to process. Are these images particularly large? If yes then try with small image.
> >
> > Uploaded folder should have write permission, if not then please grant it.
> >
> > Need to check uploaded directory structure having sub folder created with your current setting OR not, if not then try it manually may be this is again folder permission issue.

If above points is not your solution then please use wordpress plugin 'Debug My Plugin' with Debug Bar(https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-my-plugin)

It adds a debug menu to the admin bar that shows query, cache and other helpful debugging information.

Also 'Query Monitor'(http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor) is monitoring database queries, hooks, conditionals, HTTP requests, query vars, environment, redirects including automatic AJAX debugging and more.

I hope you find this detail helpful. If you have any query or suggestions to achieve the same result as above plugins does, do share with us.

Thanks!

Comment: I just want to use the wordpress debug.log file, I thought it's simple. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check for is where the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` points as that is where the `debug.log` file will be put. This can be set in `wp-config.php` e.g. `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/sites/wordpress/wp-content');`. Normally it shouldn't need to be set unless there's a non-standard setup. The value of `WP_CONTENT_DIR` may be checked as suggested in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress), or using the Wordfence plugin->Tools->Diagnostics->WordPress Settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use XAMPP to host WordPress, the log will be in Apache's error.log instead even I have wp-config.php configured.

[image: XAMPP Log]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error. What I did was to first create the debug.log file under the wp-content directory. I realized that errors were not logging in this file.
Eventually, I decided to change the permission for this file (right-click on the created debug.log file in cPanel, and click on Change Permissions). I changed to 777 (This enables write rule for the file).

I hope it helps!